# Further Filter Files Returned from Looping Through a Directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I have a pretty little piece of code that will loop through a networked drive and return the file name and extension of all files.  I have the output set to display in a listbox.  My current conundrum is that it pulls in temp files "~filename.ext" and this is throwing off my count.  How do I go about directing it to ignore all temp files "~filename.ext".

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\server\directory\folder\folder\", "*.xlsm", 
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        statusCodeLB.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string file in filePaths)
        {
            statusCodeLB.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));

        }
        statusLabel.Text = statusCodeLB.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you consider all files starting with "~" to be temp files?

Comment: Is my terminology inaccurate? I wanted to remove all files with the tilde "~" preceding the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement in the loop to check whether the file name starts with "~"  like this:

```
//...
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);

    if(filename.StartsWith("~"))
        continue; //Skip

    statusCodeLB.Items.Add(filename);
}
//...
```